# python regex negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex

when I use negative lookahead on this string

```
1pt 22px 3em 4px
```

like this

```
/\d+(?!px)/g
```

i get this result

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

and I want all of the 22px to be discarded but I don't know how should I do that

Comment: If the letters are there all the time, just use `\d+(?!px)[a-z]+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a digit pattern to the lookahead:

```
\d+(?!\d|px)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NTcW9e/1)

This way, you will not allow a digit to match after 1 or more digits are already matched.

Another way is to use an atomic group work around like

```
(?=(\d+))\1(?!px)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NTcW9e/2). Here, `(?=(\d+))` captures one or more digits into Group 1 and the `\1` backreference will consume these digits, thus preventing backtracking into the `\d+` pattern. The `(?!px)` will fail the match if the digits are followed with `px` and won't be able to backtrack to fetch `2`.

Both solutions will work with `re.findall`.

Comment: See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/95npxQ). Remember to use raw string literals when (`r'pattern'`) when declaring regex patterns.